# Remove decimal points from a decimal variable if it has .00

Tags: c#, string

I have a decimal variable and would like to convert it to a string by removing decimal points if it is .00.

For example, I have 23.00 and 25.1458 and I would like both these variables to strings as 23 and  25.1

I am using string conversion `string temp => $"{value:n0}"` but this one removes decimal points for the later variable too (25.1458) instead I just want to trim only .00 decimals

Comment: have you tried a google search for examples on how to use `string.Format` function..?

Comment: String.Format has methods to format a string but before even formating, I would like to know if its decimal part is .00

Comment: Have you tried this `temp => $"{value:.#}"`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom specifier as in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD):

> As per the docs:

The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol. If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in the result string.

Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.

The "##" format string causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 34.5 with "##" would result in the value 35.

So, in your sample, this should do the trick.

```
temp => $"{value:.#}"
```

See more [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZbJAll)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works fine but it return a Not A Number when the variable is 0